# где практиковать Java

Tags: java-8

Хелоу Программисты.
Где можно практиковать Java язык бесплатно?

Comment: Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Comment: Где-где... Дома. На форумах. И, если скиллы позволяют, на фрилансе.

Answer (score 1):

берешь любую книгу и фигачишь код, повторяешь его
берешь гитхаб и читаешь опенсорс проекты , повторяешь и дополняешь код
берешь видео уроки и повторяешь код